# Do animals get "unhealthily" fat in the wild?

Tags: zoology, ethology, medicine, fitness

Looking at a picture of a seriously fat cat, apparently directly nurtured by humans, popping up in a language learning app, I started wondering:

do animals "in the wild" (this might be ambiguous, but you can discuss it in your answer) get obese? If so: which animals and how fat? Under what conditions do they get fat?

To be more specific (following the advice of user [theforestecologist](https://biology.stackexchange.com/users/16866/theforestecologist)):

**Do they become unhealthily obese (i.e. so fat that it negatively impacts their survival)?**

Comment: Yes. Hibernating mammals store fat for the winter so that they don't have to feed all winter long. Other animals eat more fatty foods to build up their own insulating fat in order to survive colder weather.

Comment: Perhaps, though, you mean to ask "do animals become unhealthily obese?" (i.e., so fat that it negatively impacts their survival). ??

Comment: @theforestecologist I have followed your advice in the OP now, thanks.

Comment: http://sciencenordic.com/can-wild-animals-become-overweight